# Consider synonymizing [technique] and [skills]

Tags: discussion, tag-synonyms

All of the [skills](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/skills) questions could reasonably be retagged under the tag guidance for [technique](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/technique), with the possible exception of one about group-rides.

Comment: Isn't [skills] just a meta-tag which should be deleted?  It doesn't seem to be able to stand alone on a question.

Comment: @Chenmunka Reasonable question. Could one say the same of [technique]? Feel free to add "Just remove it" as an answer with your justification.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest that [skills](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/skills) is a meta-tag.  It cannot stand as the only tag on any question as it is too vague in itself.

It seems to be a prime candidate for the burnination process rather than synonimize it with anything.

Comment: This is actually a good point.  There are probably useful tags _within_ [skills], but the tag itself is too broad to be very useful.  We could probably usefully split out something like [riding-skills], but that would be a manually curated process.  (We'd also want to decide we don't want to call it [riding-techniques].)  Are there enough skills specific to the sub-discipline to have a [mtb-skills]?